# Different icons based on condition in csproj file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, icons

In my application I have two release configurations and I am able to change the splash screen based on the configuration with the condition attribute in SplashScreen like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\Splash screen\Logo1.png" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Release1'" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Splash screen\Logo2.png" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release2'" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <SplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash screen\Logo1.png" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Release1'" />
    <SplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash screen\Logo2.png" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release2'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to achieve the same thing with the applicationIcon but there is no condition attribute, how do I do?

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release1;Release2</Configurations>
        <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
        <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", ""))</RootNamespace>
        <ApplicationIcon>Resources\Icons\Icon1.ico</ApplicationIcon>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I also tried to do the same thing with the Icon in all the separate windows instead but without luck due to no condition attribute.

Comment: I believe property groups have conditions, so you could create a new conditional property group and move the icon there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have conditional property groups, so you could do something like this:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release1;Release2</Configurations>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", ""))</RootNamespace>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release1'">
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\Icons\Icon1.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release2'">
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\Icons\Icon2.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
```